# what does [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] objectForKey] return?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

if i'm doing this

```
NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
myArray = [[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"];
[myArray release];
```

am i destroying value stored in `NSUserDefaults` for key `@"array"`? Is it still extractable or not already? Does `[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"];` `return` pointer or value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to objectForKey is returning an autoreleased array.

Don't do the alloc/init or release thing around that.  You'd be leaking and most likely crashing.

Just do:

```
NSArray * myArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"array"];
```

Answer (score 2):

> am i destroying value stored in NSUserDefaults for key @"array"?

**NO**

> Is it still extractable or not already?

**Extractable**

> Does [[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"]; return pointer or value?

**Pointer. Returns pointer to object**.

---

Now your code is incorrect. You can rewrite it like this:

```
NSArray * myArray = [[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"] retain];
....
[myArray release];
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you want to get rid of the value. What you are doing is making an array with the data from `[[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"]`.

If you want to get the data and use it elsewhere:

```
NSArray * myArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"] retain];
// do stuff here
[myArray release];
```

just like beryllium said. Of course, you could have to set it first:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:anObject forKey:@"array"];
```

If you want to get rid of the data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"array"];
```

Because I honestly do not know what you are skiing, it is very hard to give you the answer you are looking for. Could you please clear it up a little?

Comment: all i wanted to do is exctract array from nsuserdefaults, set it to another array and leave array stored in nsuserdefaults undestroyed. that's all

Answer (score 0):

Store array

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"yourKey"];  
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Retrieve

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *yourArr = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```